# Why are my bash scripts within Javascript executing in reverse order?

Tags: javascript, bash, asynchronous

I apologize in advance as I know very little Javascript and have more experience in Bash.
I need to import a couple scripts in and have JS run it

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

var process = function (done) {
    var script1 = exec('sh script1.sh',
            (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                utils.output(`${stdout}`);
                utils.output(`${stderr}`);
                if (error !== null) {
                    utils.output(`exec error: ${error}`);
                }
            }); 

    var script2 = exec('sh script2.sh',
            (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                utils.output(`${stdout}`);
                utils.output(`${stderr}`);
                if (error !== null) {
                    utils.output(`exec error: ${error}`);
                }
            }); 

    utils.output(script1);
    utils.output(script2);
}
```

script1.sh:

```
echo "==== script 1 ===="
```

script2.sh:

```
echo "==== script 2 ===="
```

Output:

```
==== script 2 ====
==== script 1 ====
```

Why are those outputting in reverse order?

Comment: This is a synchronous issue (It looks to me anyway) ... Light reading: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript

Comment: `exec()` is asynchronous. They're probably executing concurrently, and the output is printed in the order that they finish.

Comment: Try adding a `sleep` command to scipt 2 and it will be printed last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barbar stated, this is because exec() is asynchronous.

Thanks everyone.